# Entire top level domain won't load (.edu)

Tags: windows, networking

Unfortunately, I don't know much about the problem as it was relayed to be through another person.  All I know is that she can't load any *.edu site, and she's running windows.  Any idea where I should start with this one?

Comment: Some people try to be 'safe' on the internet and will use programs like PeerBlock/PeerGuardian which will block certain websites; one of which can be educational sites.

Comment: Without much more information it is difficult to see what's really going on here. She could have something in her HOSTS file that is blocking it. She could also be at a university and they're blocking other university's websites. who knows.

Comment: Yeah it's quite hard to troubleshoot.  I don't even know if this is a recent happening or not.

Comment: Don't bother with hosts. You can't block entire tlds in there, you can't even use any kind of wildcard. There's probably something funny going on at her DNS server.

Comment: I'll definitely have her check the hosts file.  That was my first thought as well.  Also I don't know which windows she's on.  It's probably 7, but could be XP.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know you couldn't use a wildcard for hosts.  Maybe I'll have her point to an open dns.

Comment: Trying a different DNS server would be a good first start. OpenDNS: `208.67.222.222`, `208.67.220.220`. Google DNS: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: Is this not the right place for a question like this?  I don't understand the downvote.  @nhinkle, thanks I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Ideally attempt tracert's and DNS lookups from her machine as the resulting error messages/failures will tell you where the problem is... But first port  of call would be a [Malware check](http://www.malwarebytes.org)!

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the problem clarified in great detail. For example:

1) What are a few specific sites she has tried? (If possible, have her type the exact site names.)

2) How precisely has she tried them?

3) What are a few sites that did work when she tried those sites the same way?

4) For the sites that didn't work, what exactly happened?

You have a terribly vague problem description. Your first order of business is to flesh it out.

Comment: Thanks. yeah she's teaching abroad and not super easy to reach, so I wanted to be able to ask her everything I needed at once.